Uniformly convex and smooth Banach spaces
Is there an infinite dimensional Banach space with a norm that is both uniformly convex with a modulus of power type $2$ and uniformly smooth with a modulus of power type $2$ which is not a Hilbert space?

No. Every such space is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.  By a Theorem of Pisier (Theorem 3.7.1 in [1]) one has that, for a Banach space $X$,

$X$ is $p$-smooth (for an equivalent norm) if and only if $X$ has martingale type $p$.
$X$ is $q$-convex (for an equivalent norm) if and only if $X$ has martingale cotype $q$.

If you are not familiar with the concept of martingale type you can check [1].
Hence if $X$ is 2-smooth and 2-convex then $X$ has martingale type 2 and martingale cotype 2. In particular, $X$ has type 2 and cotype 2. This implies that $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space. See my previous answer for more details.
[1] Analysis in Banach spaces volume I
